# Java OpenGL 3.x - Apply Square Texture to Circle Model

Tags: java, opengl, textures, geometry

I have a way to generate the verities for a circle like object in OpenGL. It does so off of a variable number, if the number is 360, 360 individual triangles will makeup the circle.

My Question is how do you apply a square texture to the entire circle so that it squishes the texture to fit the circle?

**EDIT codes:**

`LoD` => Level of Detail.

```
public static float[] getVerts( int LoD ){
    float[] _spokeArray = new float[ (LoD*2) ];
    double rad = (360.0d / LoD) * (Math.PI / 180.0d);
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < LoD ; i++ ) {
        _spokeArray[ i*2 + 0 ] = (float) Math.cos( rad*i );
        _spokeArray[ i*2 + 1 ] = (float) Math.sin( rad*i );
    }
    float[] _vertArray = new float[ (LoD*9) ];
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < LoD ; i++ ) {
        _vertArray[ i*9 + 0 ] = 0.0f;
        _vertArray[ i*9 + 1 ] = 0.0f;
        _vertArray[ i*9 + 2 ] = 0.0f;

        _vertArray[ i*9 + 3 ] = _spokeArray[ i*2 + 0 ];
        _vertArray[ i*9 + 4 ] = _spokeArray[ i*2 + 1 ];
        _vertArray[ i*9 + 5 ] = 0.0f;

        if ( (i+1) == LoD ){
            _vertArray[ i*9 + 6 ] = 1.0f;
            _vertArray[ i*9 + 7 ] = 0.0f;
            _vertArray[ i*9 + 8 ] = 0.0f;
            break;
        }

        _vertArray[ i*9 + 6 ] = _spokeArray[ (i+1)*2 + 0 ];
        _vertArray[ i*9 + 7 ] = _spokeArray[ (i+1)*2 + 1 ];
        _vertArray[ i*9 + 8 ] = 0.0f;
    }

    return _vertArray;
}

public void setUpTexture() throws GLException, IOException {
    texture = TextureIO.newTexture( imagePath, true );
}

public void draw(GL gl) {
    gl.glBindBuffer( GL3.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, Main._scene.indexOf( this ) );

    texture.enable( gl );
    texture.bind(   gl );
            // The indices are just: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... LoD*3
    gl.glDrawElements( GL.GL_TRIANGLES, indBuffer.capacity(), GL.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0 );
}
```

Comment: show your code...what you have worked on so far...

Answer (score 0):

Mapping a texture square to a disk would result on strong distortions.

Normally, only the interior disk portion of the texture square is used (some space is wasted) and your texture coordinates would be your unit disk vertex coordinates (adjusted from [-1,1] to [0,1]). example for vertex `i`:

```
float u = _vertArray[i*9 + 0] * .5f + .5f;
float v = _vertArray[i*9 + 1] * .5f + .5f;
```

To still distort the square texture to completely map the disk, a possible distortion is the use of `Lp`-Norm with a high `p` to mimic infinity:

```
float const p = 30.f; // to adjust
float const epsilon = 0.00001f; // to adjust
float x  = _vertArray[i*9 + 0];
float y  = _vertArray[i*9 + 1];
float l2 = sqrt(x*x + y*y);
float lp = pow( pow(abs(x),p) + pow(abs(y),p), 1.f/p);
float xp = 0.f;
float yp = 0.f;
if( lp > epsilon )
{
    xp = x * l / lp;
    yp = y * l / lp;
}
float u  = xp * .5f + .5f;
float v  = yp * .5f + .5f;
```